# Grepping Multiple Entries on a Line

Tags: unix, command-line, grep, zsh, bsd

I am trying to `grep` a file against another file; however, I am having trouble with multiple entries on one line.

Here is a simplified example of my setup:

```
grep -of <(echo "VHDL\nC++\nHello") <(echo "C++ VHDL")
```

which outputs

```
VHDL
```

when I am trying to get it to output

```
C++
VHDL
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I am using BSD `grep`, not GNU `grep` which works as desired.

Comment: Have you tested the output of `echo "VHDL\nC++\nHello"`? Hint: `echo` doesn't interpret backslash escapes.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am using BSD `echo` which is printing the new line characters.

Comment: If you use Bash, `echo` uses the builtin (which doesn't interpret backslash escapes without the `-e` option), not the system command. You seem to be using Bash, as process substitution is a Bashism. What does `type echo` return?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oops. You are right. It seems adding @bishop's fix `$` results in an output of just `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is valid. However, your `echo "VHDL\nC++\nHello"` outputs one line, not three. This happens because `echo` does not interpret escape characters, so you need to use some mechanism to insert them into your stream. Assuming you're on bash:

```
$ grep -of <(echo $'VHDL\nC++\nHello') <(echo "C++ VHDL")
C++
VHDL
```

Comment: I am using BSD `echo` which does output new lines. Although, this command works with linux `grep` it doesn't work as expected using the BSD grep, which is were the issue lies.

Comment: Which BSD and shell? FreeBSD and bash did not echo new lines for me.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using the system's BSD echo, I was using `zsh`'s echo which does print the new lines. You are correct. BSD echo doesn't print newlines. Also, bash doesn't print new lines either. Zsh seems to be the odd one out.

Comment: Did you try `echo -e` in bash?